# Replace words in string that match word in a separate array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to add a # in front of any words in a string that match a set of 'filter' words in an array.

```
This is what I have so far
let wordsArray = ['she', 'smile'];
let sentence = 'She has a big smile';
let sentenceArray = sentence.split(" ");
wordsArray.forEach((i, vals) => {
    sentenceArray.forEach((j, sVal) => {
        if (sVal === vals) {
            sentenceArray[j] = `#${j}`;
            console.log(sentenceArray)
        }
    })
});
```

This is what it is spitting out in the console.

```
app.js:17 (5) ["She", "has", "a", "big", "smile", She: "#She"]
 app.js:17 (5) ["She", "has", "a", "big", "smile", She: "#She", has:
 "#has"] app.js:23 She has a big smile
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[Repl Example](https://repl.it/repls/IncompatibleQuerulousExams)

You can use `Array.map` to iterate through each word in the sentence, then if it matches return the word with a `#` symbol.

```
let wordsArray = ['she', 'smile'];
let sentence = 'She has a big smile';
let sentenceArray = sentence.split(" ");
sentenceArray = sentenceArray.map((word) => {
  let matchIndex = wordsArray.indexOf(word.toLowerCase())
  return (matchIndex !== -1)
    ? '#'.concat(word)
    : word
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of the `forEach` callback is the *index*, you're currently iterating over, not the value. You should also call `toLowerCase` on the word in the sentence to compare against the lower-cased word in the `wordsArray`:

```js
let wordsArray = ['she', 'smile'];
let sentence = 'She has a big smile';
let sentenceArray = sentence.split(" ");
wordsArray.forEach((vals) => {
    sentenceArray.forEach((sVal, j) => {
        if (sVal.toLowerCase() === vals) {
            sentenceArray[j] = `#${sVal}`;
        }
    })
});
console.log(sentenceArray)
```

But rather than a nested loop, constructing a Set of the `wordsArray` would be less computationally complex (`O(n)` instead of `O(n ^ 2)`), in addition to being more elegant:

```js
const wordsArray = ['she', 'smile'];
const wordsSet = new Set(wordsArray);
const sentence = 'She has a big smile';
const result = sentence.split(" ")
  .map(word => wordsSet.has(word.toLowerCase()) ? '#' + word : word);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Our answers are very similar and we posted seconds apart. Heh.

Comment: The second solution that you posted performs very poorly in benchmark tests. I don't benchmark test unless there are many similar solutions to the same problem. At that point it comes down to either legibility or performance. I think it must be `Set` that is slowing things down. Seems true it is more elegant.

Comment: If the inputs are large enough that the millions of operations that modern computers can perform every second isn't quick enough, then the Set approach will far outshine the array approach. On tiny inputs like those in the question, `O(n)` vs `O(n ^ 2)` is unnoticeable.

Answer (score 0):

```
wordsArray.forEach((word) =>sentence = sentence.replace(new RegExp(word,"ig"),"#"+word))
```

Iterates over all the words in teh filter then replaces the words in the sentence using a regular expression new RegExp(word, "ig") first argument is the phrase to be matched second argument "ig" is just flags, "i" ignores case sensitivity, "g" searches globally.

Comment: This is the most condensed answer, but it performs 52% slower than using `Array.map` with `indexOf` to match woreds. Probably because of the `RegExp`.

Comment: But the code is shorter how can it be slower :> jokes aside i didn't really consider complexity  but it certainly doesn't hurt to keep it in mind.

Comment: When the solutions are all very similar then the best solution has to be the easiest to read or the fastest, otherwise I don't usually have a need to test performance.